# Javafx : Is there any way Like in JPanel Swing revalidation or repaint in javafx

Tags: javafx

I am Stuck in problem Like in JPanel we update content of it using repaint and revalidate method is there any way to do it with HBox in Javafx.

Comment: Why would you need to repaint things manually? A few lines of code and a more specific explanation would help us understand your question better.

Comment: There isn't, and it isn't needed. JavaFX has an API for [observable properties](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) and [observable collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/collections-tutorial/collections.htm#JFXCL107). The containers (such as `HBox`) use these and observe them, so they "know" when things have changed. As suggested, give an example of why you think you need this, with a [MCVE].